# Django log the requests using apache kafka

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, thrift

I want to log the every request coming to Django and save to mongo db like this sample
http://engineering.hackerearth.com/2015/02/26/logging-millions-requests-what-it-takes/

want to call something like this.

```
# this creates a thread which collects required data and forwards
# it to the transporter cluster
run_async(log_request_async, request)
```

How can I do this inside django request.? any samples to call runasync ?